# Accessing form's resources (resx file) from code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If I have a form Frm1.cs that is using some icons, images or other resources, these resources get stored in the form's resx file (Frm1.resx).

My simple question is how do I access these resources from code?

As a workaround I can store these resources in the Project resource file and they will be available via `Properties.Resources.resourcename`. 
However, similar syntax does not work for the resources stored in the form's resource file.

While searching for a solution I have come across several references to  [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx) class but was not able to find a way to use that to access the form's resources...

Comment: Did you see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465405/access-the-value-from-resource-file-programmatically

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The way to access local form resources is through an instance of ResourceManager.
Suppose you got two PictureBox in a Form called Frm1:

```
var resources = new ResourceManager(typeof(Frm1));
var image = (Bitmap)resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image");

pictureBox2.Image = image;
```

Hope this could help you...

Answer (score 1):

If you use visual studio designer to add resources, you get a class `Resources` with static properties to access them.

To access:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.MyResourceImage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Harold Coppoolse's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63808753/530172), Visual Studio (speaking from 2022 Community) has some nice automation when it comes to accessing any given Form's resources.

### Edit Resource file

With every Form created in Visual Studio, there should be an associated `.resx` generated along with it (if an item with a `Text` property is inserted, for example.) When you open the `.resx` file in the Designer tool, there's an **Access Modifier:** option. Change it to the most restrictive permission possible in your language (there should be no reason to use `Public`), and this will generate a `FormName`.Designer.*code extension* file underneath the `.resx` file.

### What's happening in the background?

In the background, Visual Studio is using `ResGen.exe` to [generate the strongly-typed resource class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/resgen-exe-resource-file-generator#generating-a-strongly-typed-resource-class) to accompany the `.resx` file. What this does is create a class in the namespace specified by the `Custom Tool Namespace` `.resx` file property, with:

- A parameterless constructor, which can be used to instantiate the strongly typed resource class.
- A static (C#) or Shared (Visual Basic) and read-only ResourceManager property, which returns the ResourceManager instance that manages the strongly typed resource.
- A static Culture property, which allows you to set the culture used for resource retrieval. By default, its value is null, which means that the current UI culture is used.
- One static (C#) or Shared (Visual Basic) and read-only property for each resource in the .resources file. The name of the property is the name of the resource.-

This means that, in code, you simply use `*Namespace*`.`*FormClassName*`.`*ResourceName*` to access any resource you need. No extra code is required on your part.