# Resource File lookup with variable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, resx

Project type: C# Mvc 4

Hi all I was wondering if anyone with experience in Resource files can help me:

I have a basic setup for string localization so I have created resource files for different cultures and they work fine, i.e. In the view if you put:

`@Resources.Title`

It successfully looks up the string with the key title in the resource file respective to the active culture on your browser.

The question I have is if it is possible to do the lookup dynamically e.g.:

`@Resources.Model.Title`    where `Model.Title` is a variable known at runtime

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at the [ResourcesManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing form's resources (resx file) from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642623/accessing-forms-resources-resx-file-from-code)
Flagging this one because there's an older question asking the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
@Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(Model.Title)
```

There is also an overload where you can supply a `CultureInfo` to get the string in a different language then the current one. Otherwise the culture from the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` is used.