# Access the value from resource file programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

Came across a situation that requires accessing string value stored in resource file based on the key provided from code behind.

how can i do this?

**Note**: the resource file exist in a web project in my solution which i want to access from my silverlight application..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resource File lookup with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333194/resource-file-lookup-with-variable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing form's resources (resx file) from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642623/accessing-forms-resources-resx-file-from-code)
Flagging this one because there's an older question asking the same question.

Answer (score 27):

You can use [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx) class:

```
ResourceManager myManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(MyResource));
string myString = myManager.GetString("StringKey");
```

Comment: what is `MyResource` above?

Comment: It's your resource class name e.g. `StringResources`, `Resource1` etc Basicaly it's the name of your `res` file.

Comment: You may need to include it (`using`) or use a name with namespace e.g. `MyApplication.Resource.MessagesResources`

Comment: my resource file exists in a web project in my solution and i want to access it from silverlight project (in same solution)

Comment: Used it for requesting translated string from resources. This works! Thanks.

Comment: ResourceManager myManager = MyResource.ResourceManager also works.

Comment: Would this work for localized resource files?
Such as it will know the difference between MyResource.en.resx and MyResource.de.resx, depending on current language?

Comment: @axa yes it would work. According to documentation `GetString("key")` uses current UI culture. You can also get value using specific culture e.g. `GetString("key", new CultureInfo("es-ES"))`.

Answer (score 10):

Assume that your resource file name is "Resource.resx", and you want to pass key dynamically then,

```
using System.Resources;
string resVal = Resource.ResourceManager.GetString(dynamicKeyVal);
```

Let me know if it not works, I will work on it and will provide the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 5):

i generally access resource like this way

```
Resources.MyLocalised.CompanyName;
```

Comment: a lot nicer than GetString

Answer (score 3):

You can use as following no need to create `ResourceManager` instance.Resource file already has inherited from `ResourceManager`.

```
string value = MyResource.ResourceManager.GetString("stringKey");
```

**Note:**`MyResource` is shared resource file Name.

Comment: my resource file exists in a web project in my solution and i want to access it from silverlight project (in same solution)

Comment: If you want to share your resource file within the more projects you should keep that resource file into common assembly and add the refference for both .

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
string resourceValue = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("resxFilename", "resourceKey").ToString();
```

Comment: Clearly Rohan asks for something different: "requires accessing string value stored in resource file **based on the key provided from code behind**"

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple ".resx" files of different languages under "Properties" and dynamically change the resource file. Then you get the value of a particular key from code behind like this. You don't have to mention the ".resx" file name. It will automatically get the value from the currently set ".resx" file (culture):

```
string str=[ProjectName].Properties.Resources.[ResourceKeyName]
```