# How do I use a string resource file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using `Visual Studio 2022` and I am struggling to figure out how to properly embed and use a resource file in order to use `GetString()`.

teadates.txt:

```ini
DEC=December
MAR=March
```

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-resource-files) from Micrsoft I used ResGen to generate a resource binary:

```
resgen teadates.txt
```

This produced a `teadates.resources` file. I've tried multiple ways to embed this `teadates.resources` file, but nothing seems to work.

Embed Method 1:

1. Right-click project >> `Properties`
2. In the right pane click `Resources`
3. Here I add the existing `teadates.resources` file

Embed Method 2:

1. In `Solution Explorer` locate the `teadates.resources` file
2. In `Properties` set the `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`

Code:

```
// Fails to compile
// CS0234: The type or namespace name 'teadates' does not exist
//     in the namespace 'TeaSpace' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
String tmp1 = TeaSpace.teadates.ResourceManager.GetString("DEC");

// Fails to compile
// CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'ResourceManager'
//     and no accessible extension method 'ResourceManager' accepting a
//     first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a
//     using directive or an assembly reference?)
String tmp2 = TeaSpace.Properties.Resources.teadates.ResourceManager.GetString("DEC");

// Compiles, fails on runtime when executing rm.GetString("DEC")
// System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any
//     resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.
//     Make sure "teadates.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into
//     assembly "TeaCup" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies
//     required are loadable and fully signed.'
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("teadates", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
String tmp3 = rm.GetString("DEC");

// Compiles, doesn't fail on runtime, but rm.GetString("DEC") returns null
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("TeaSpace.Properties.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
String tmp4 = rm.GetString("DEC");
```

`tmp1` is completely wrong. It doesn't even find the resource. `tmp2` seems to find it, but it can't use ResourceManager because it's a `byte[]`. `tmp3` compiles as it seems it doesn't check for the file on compile time and only run time. `tmp4` compiles and doesn't fail on runtime, but returns null.

I've tried searching, including StackOverflow. I've found questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465405/access-the-value-from-resource-file-programmatically), but all answers gloss over all the details. They all just have the code to use the `ResourceManager` or `Properties` which I've tried above unsuccessfully. The Microsoft documentation I linked is good up until compiling. It uses the command line whereas I'm trying to use the IDE.

Comment: In the Resources editor in VS, make sure you have "Strings" selected in the drop down for the type of resource. If you are adding a text file under "Images", it will be treated as a byte[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed a .txt string resource file by following these steps:

1. Add the .txt file to your project.
2. In the Properties window for the .txt file, set the Build Action to **Embedded resource**.
3. Edit the .csproj file, find the `<EmbeddedResource>` element for the .txt file, and add two child elements:

   ```xml
   <EmbeddedResource Include="teadates.txt">
     <ManifestResourceName>TeaDates</ManifestResourceName>
     <Type>Resx</Type>
   </EmbeddedResource>
   ```
4. Use ResourceManager.GetString to read the resource value:

   ```csharp
   ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("TeaDates", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
   Console.WriteLine(rm.GetString("MAR")); // March
   ```

   The first argument to the ResourceManager constructor must match the `<ManifestResourceName>` in the .csproj file.

Comment: This worked for me. Is there a way to accomplish step 3 within the IDE without manually editing the csproj file? If not I'll accept this as the answer, but I'm a tad worried the manual changes could get overwritten.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is. Instead of using a .txt file, which Visual Studio doesn't seem to support all that well, you might alternatively consider storing your strings inside a .resx file, which Visual Studio fully supports. (This is NineBerry's first suggestion.)

Answer (score 1):

Step-by-step instructions to add strings from a text file to a C# Visual Studio project.

1. You have a text file `teadates.txt` with a content like

```ini
DEC=December
MAR=March
```

2. Execute this command on the commandline:

`resgen teadates.txt teadates.resx`

Note that we specify a file with the `resx` extension as target file so that the XML resx format is used instead of the binary *.resources format.

3. In Visual Studio, right click the project and choose "Add Existing Item" and choose the `teadates.resx` file.
4. Select the newly added file in the Solution Explorer and change these properties:

Set `Custom Tool` to `ResXFileCodeGenerator`.

[image]

Note that a teadates.Designer.cs file is now automatically added to the Solution Explorer.

5. You can now access the string resources from code via for example `teadates.DEC`

[image]

Or access the resource manager:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(teadates.DEC);
        Console.WriteLine(teadates.ResourceManager.GetString("DEC"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if teadates.txt is updated later, this approach requires that you manually regenerate teadates.resx and (if any strings were added or deleted) teadates.Designer.cs.

Comment: If an update is made, it is sufficient to copy the newly generated *.resx file to the project. The C# code will be automatically updated.

Comment: Did you actually try it? The .Designer.cs file won't be regenerated unless you manually resave the .resx file from within Visual Studio.

Comment: @MichaelLiu You are correct. The designer.cs file is not automatically updated until you touch the *.resx file in Visual Studio