# How to extract the resources stored in .resx file of vb.net project

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have vb.net project. To that project I have added many resources ( icons, images etc). Those resources are stored in file named with extension .resx.  Now I want to extract all the resources specially icons form that project. Is there any ways to do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing form's resources (resx file) from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642623/accessing-forms-resources-resx-file-from-code)
Flagging this one because there's an older question asking the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285720/Extract-Images-and-Icons-of-NET-Resources) I got the answer for my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ResourceManager class. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
' Creates the ResourceManager.
Dim myManager As New _
   System.Resources.ResourceManager("ResourceNamespace.myResources", _
   myAssembly)

Dim myImage As System.Drawing.Image
myImage = CType(myManager.GetObject("ImageResource"), _
    System.Drawing.Image)
```

Comment: I have tried this, 
Try
Dim myAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly
myAssembly = Me.GetType.Assembly
Dim myManager As New  _System.Resources.ResourceManager("ResourceNamespace.myResources", _myAssembly)                                                                                           
Dim myImage As System.Drawing.Image myImage = CType(myManager.GetObject("btn_webRply.Image"),  _System.Drawing.Image) myImage.Save("d:\11.bmp")
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox("Error message")
 End Try

Comment: But it is giving error message as,
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "ResourceNamespace.myResources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "WinData" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.